# How to remove the minimum and maximum value(only one min and only one max, not all of them) from an ArrayList<Double> in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, max, min

How can i remove the minimum and maximum value(only one min and only one max, not all of them) from an ArrayList, in Java, and put it in another ArrayList?

```
List<Double> arrayOfDoubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Comment: Write some code that finds the lowest and stores it somewhere then finds the highest and stores it somewhere.

Comment: (1) find max and min in list (2) remove them. If any part of this solution is unclear ask us about (don't forget to include your code attempts so we could explain where you made mistakes)

Comment: And now the question has changed

Comment: Why is your variable named `arrayOfInts` when it contains `Double`s?

Comment: One question: is this homework assignment? I'm just asking because if it is, is suspect that its purpose would be teaching you how to create your own code which will use loops. If that is the case then you most probably will not get points for using methods from `Collections` class.

Comment: no, is for my personal use, i am learning Java, i like it :)

Comment: To answer the question it's necessary to know if the minimum and maximum value can appear multiple times and, if yes, how this should be handled. (Should all minimum values be removed and should all of them be put in the new ArrayList?)

Comment: well, i dont want all of the same min/max values removed, only one min and one max

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ***How can i remove the minimum and maximum value from an ArrayList, in Java, and put it in another ArrayList?***

You can use [`Collections.min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29), and [`.max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
Double min = Collections.min(arrayOfInts);
Double max = Collections.max(arrayOfInts);
arrayOfInts.remove(min);
if (min != max)
    arrayOfInts.remove(max);

List<Double> minMaxList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(min, max));
```